# Is printing not allowing within a service in android?

Tags: java, android, printing

I wrote a service in android app to read a pdf file and send to the print using print manager. but it not allowing to print, and it says " IllegalStateException : Can print only from an activity".IS this a problem of newer android versions?

This is the cade

```
  PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
  PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = new PdfDocumentAdapter(pathPdfRead);
  String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + newDoc;
  printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

I'm expecting some answer. Is this possible in Android 11 or higher versions?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is self-explanatory:

> IllegalStateException : Can print only from an ***activity***

So if you do such implementation in a **Service**, the `this` in this line is not an **Activity Context**:

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

You must have an **Activity Context** in order to make it work.

Comment: Which means should I do this in an activity class or do I have another way?

Comment: Yes, in such case you need to have your print function in an Activity. And you can make use of, like, BroadcastReceiver, or if possible, bind your Service to Activity so that you can trigger the print function in Activity from your Service.